# Issue with Windows 10 Installation. Possibly BIOS/UEFI related

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi

I have in my PC 4 drives. 2 SSDs with Ubuntu, 1 empty SSD and 1 empty HDD. In the empty SSD I want to install Windows 10.

I have installed Windows 100s of times in the past but this time I have encountered only problems. I created a bootable USB using Rufus, I physically disconnected the 2 SSDs with the Ubuntu, changed the boot order and I either received the messages you see in the following pictures or I got stuck in a black screen with nothing happening. When I removed the USB the black screen was bypassed and I was redirected to the BIOS screen.

I tried in both USB 2 and USB 3 ports and I also tried both in Legacy/UEFI and in UEFI modes, with no success. Moreover, I tried the option MRB in Rufus and also I tried using a different USB flash drive, but again there was no success. I had never faced these issues in the past and I never had to change options in my BIOS, I don't understand what is happening!

**Solution**

The problem was due to Rufus. I tried the same bootable flash drive in a different computer and it had the same results. After using the Windows software tool for the creation of bootable flash drives the installation was performed as it should.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you attempting to install Windows while Legacy mode is enabled? You need to disable it

Comment: @Ramhound I did disable it and tried in UEFI only, I mention that in my post.

Comment: Both of your screenshots show otherwise.

Comment: @Ramhound As I mentioned in the post, the errors in the screenshots were not produced all the time. When the mode was UEFI only the installation never began and I was only stuck in a blank screen. Also in UEFI if I used a USB 2 port then only the first error message would be produced.

Comment: What settings did you use with Rufus. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound There was only one setting that I was allowed to edit and that was regarding GPT and MBR. I tried both options. All the other settings had no available options beyond the defaults.

Comment: please tell us what kins od pc and vendors has been used, for dell and hp remind that you need to select uefi boot specifically

Comment: [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) should _never_ be enabled, as its **sole purpose** was to support booting distros that didn't yet support EFI Boot circa <2017; the only reason to enable it is if accessing a legacy Option ROM. Rufus autoselects everything once the ISO is chosen. Verify the boot drive order in the UEFI firmware - if you manually select the drive Windows is installed to from the UEFI boot menu, will it boot? It can only be two things, either the UEFI boot order or the SATA port used doesn't support booting from it.

Comment: @Adam Rufus should be auto-selecting Large FAT32 for the install USB's filesystem ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/DBPJRlz)), but if it's not showing that as an option, use a larger USB drive or a USB HDD to not have it use NTFS. If you don't have either available, you'll need to use the Windows ADK's [`MakeWinPeMedia`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/makewinpemedia-command-line-options?view=windows-11) to make a bootable USB from the extracted ISO's contents (`MakeWinPEMedia /Ufd "C:\extracted\ISO\path" Z:`)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author resolved their problem by recreating the installation media with Microsoft’s Media Creation Tool instead of Rufus

Comment: I'm fine with closing this issue too (even as I am the main developer of Rufus). Another possibility, that would explain why it failed on 2 machines and was resolved when using the MCT, is that OP's original ISO that they used with Rufus was corrupted, and since the MCT recreates the ISO content, it wouldn't be affected.

Comment: @Akeo I always use Rufus for creating bootable media and I never faced an issue before.  As a matter of fact I will keep using it in the future. The ISO that I used was download directly from Microsoft, which doesn't mean it couldn't be corrupted I guess.

Comment: @Adam, just to be safe, you may want to validate its SHA-1 by following [this entry from the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_validate_that_a_Windows_ISO_is_a_genuine_retail_version). I'd also be interested in a copy of the `efi\boot\bootx64.efi` from the large NTFS partition in the media you created. You can sent it to support@akeo.ie if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing a few things that may help you troubleshoot your issue.

1. In UEFI mode, your Secure Boot status reports `Setup` mode rather than `Enabled`. This appears to hint at your Secure Boot configuration either missing the default keys or not being completed. The first thing I would do is disable Secure Boot altogether and see if that works better.
2. It appears that your UEFI firmware does include an NTFS driver (`An NTFS driver service is already loaded`), but that this driver **may** be unable to properly read the `bootx64.efi` bootloader residing on the NTFS partition. Unfortunately, this appears to be a relatively common occurrence, where the NTFS driver included in a UEFI firmware is limited to a few operations and cannot be used a generic file system driver. This would explain why, when trying to load and execute the `bootx64.efi` bootloader, you get an error. Either that or you are using a `bootx64.efi` bootloader that isn't actually designed for x86 64-bit architectures for some reason, but that shouldn't be the case if you're using a retail Windows ISO. Unfortunately, it is not possible to force the use of a different NTFS driver, so you may be stuck with whatever limitations the one that's embedded in your UEFI firmware has...
3. If you are booting in legacy mode, you should follow the indications given in the second bullet point of the message you get for BIOS boot, though, I seem to understand that, when you tried that, you only got a black screen. Please be mindful however that some computers may just be very slow to boot, with a black screen displaying for many minutes before the Windows installer screen starts to display.

At any rate, if your UEFI firmware does have an NTFS driver (and your screenshot shows it does) then you should be able to demonstrate to your hardware manufacturer that they need to fix something if simply extracting the Windows ISO content to a single NTFS partition does not work. Because if their NTFS driver is compliant with the UEFI specs, you should be able to do just that and boot from the NTFS partition, in UEFI mode, to install Windows. So if that doesn't work, it's up to your computer manufacturer to fix this issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132646/discussion-on-answer-by-akeo-issue-with-windows-10-installation-possibly-bios-u).